# Bind Memeber function to another member

Tags: c++, function, pointers, bind

I want a system where an object inside a class can call a function inside that class when assigned.

like this collider component example:

```
 class colliderComponent
{
  void Collide()
{
//call the assigned function 
}

}



 class object
{
public:
void collideDelegate()
{
 // do something
}

public:
  collidercomponent* cc;

 Object()
{
 cc-> //assign collide delegate to be called on Collide()
}
}
```

Comment: You could probably use `std::function` and `std::bind` to do this.

Comment: how exactly? Im still pretty new to c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `std::function` and `std::bind`.
Here is an example ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ek6ipL)):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class colliderComponent
{
public:
void Collide()
{
collideDelegate(); 
}
std::function<void()> collideDelegate;
};



class Object
{
public:
void collideDelegate()
{
    std::cout << "collide delgate" << std::endl;
}

public:
  colliderComponent* cc;

Object(colliderComponent* cc) : cc(cc)
{
 cc->collideDelegate = std::bind(&Object::collideDelegate,this); //assign collide delegate to be called on Collide()
}
};

int main()
{
    colliderComponent cc;
    Object o(&cc);
    cc.Collide();
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. what about adding parameters to the delegate?

Comment: You mean you want to set parameters of `cc`. Or do you want to call the bound function with parameters?

Comment: Add parameters to collideDelegate() in  Object.

Comment: Lets assume we have `Object::collideDelegate(int i)`, then in `colliderComponent::collideDelegate`'s type must change to `std::function<void(int)>`. Finally you bind it via `cc->collideDelegate = std::bind(&Object::collideDelegate,this,std::placeholders::_1);`. Now, since you have an unbound argument, you need a placeholder.